# Truncate database in mysql server by half?

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql server with large DB  over 100 Gigs with lots of tables; I would like to set up a test server with half of the records in DB; what could be the best query to  do it ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: according to the replies given below , I was trying to make something below

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(SET @NUM=SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME', ';' DELETE FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' LIMIT NUM) 
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test';

Comment: the above query wont work since its wrong btw is there anyway I can make it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use percona-xtrabackup backup the origin DB, then restore the DB on target server.
2. delete from tab_x limit NUM, NUM=select count(*)/2 from tab_x;

PS: when delete so many rows, turn off the target server mysql binlog write, can save binlog files.

Comment: delete from tab_x limit NUM, NUM=select count(*) from tab_x; will delete all, though you plan to wrote - NUM=select count(*)/2 from tab_x; isnt it?

Comment: @WenchengJi This would be awesome; BTW I am using mariadb 10.2 Galera ; So I would like to use their tool "mariabackup" ; Could u please give me commands to take backups using "mariabackup" without locking and if any backup script so I can run everynight in Production servers; I am using mysqldump at the moment which is too long; I know mariabackup can be used similar to xrtabackup but nobody gives a right cmd in full using mariabackup. Could you please ?

Comment: @WenchengJi  I was trying your query but it returned an error Undeclared variable   "ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: NUM"; why is that so ? How can I make it work.

Answer (score 2):

there is no single query for this, but first what you need to analyze:

- are all tables have a similar size or not?
- if any relations explicit or implicit?

often case when only a few tables take 80% of space, and in this case, you can copy all other as is and a half for biggest tables.

if foreign keys enabled - you must prepare a proper sequence of queries
if no foreign keys - you must think, do you strictly require data consistency or it just a test data and this moment not important

Comment: Even without `FOREIGN KEYS`, there are likely to be dependencies that invalidate any simple method of cutting the data in half.

Comment: sure! it possible in most of the cases.